# How to alter Safari's default cursor options

Tags: macos, safari

Bear with me as I explain how Safari prompts a user to search:

Previously, when I would open Safari or open a new tab within Safari, there would be no cursor present (I think). When I would begin typing, all inserted text would be placed in the address bar/URL bar.

However, I recently had to reinstall Safari due to contacting malware. Now I have to manually click the address bar or use the "Command + L" shortcut. Otherwise, when I type, it goes nowhere or (as my homepage is Google) typing puts text into the Google search field/search bar.

What are the default settings for Safari, and how can I change this so Safari's default position is to accept initial typing into the address bar?

For the record, I am using MacBook Pro (13-inch Mid 2012), OS X Yosemite (10.10.3)

EDIT: My main point in asking this is to understand how Safari sets the "typing location". Previously, if I began tying, it would go to the URL bar. Now, there's a pause as the Google homepage loads, and I type there.

Comment: How and from where did you reinstall ?

Comment: @Buscar웃SD Yes, to be clear, I didn't fully uninstall Safari. i manually removed Safari files from Library, Application Support Files, Preferences, etc. So, I am sure there were some remnants that remained (it's just a feature of OS X...)